# I want to show progress bar in django template, on the basis of django post process/progress(form is ajax submit). is it possible?

Tags: ajax, django, post, django-templates

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
if attorney_data_list:
    for i in len(attorney_data_list):
        if(index%3 == 0):
            process_percent = int(100 * float(index) / float(len(case_data_list)+1))

else:
    pass
```

> i want this process_percent value in django template on every for loop.is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Standard HTTP connections are request / response based, meaning that you only send the response to the browser once the function completely ran.
To provide the current process from within this function, you would probably need to use websockets, though I am not really familiar with them.

With standard HTTP-requests, you could use the database to store the process_percentage and use another ajax-request to retrieve the process_percentage from the database and send it to the browser.

Comment: thanks for your reply. What you suggested here is logically correct. but i have one query.  is it right way to hit database every time for this task?

Comment: The problem is, that with HTTP you have no chance of sending intermediate messages to the client. Probably the best way would be to use websockets which, if I understand them correctly, can be used perfectly for what you require. With standard HTTP you will need to use some workaround like hitting the DB each time. You could, of course, also use some kind of in-memory storage that can be accessed from different threads instead of the DB.